# How can I replace one key with another key in Autohotkey even in the middle of a word?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I have been using Autohotkey (AHK) for a long time but I still don't know how to do a simple key replacement and I also was not able to find the answer with a google search. On my keyboard (Finnish) I have a button which produces `å` (or `Å` with shift) when I press it. I would like to change that to `ü` (and `Ü` respectively) because I use `ü` much more than `å` :)

`::å::ü` does not work at all! And it should also work in the middle of a word (because single letters usually appear in the middle of words ;)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not replying earlier. Your code above helped me to get started. Unfortunately, it wasn't quite that easy. However, in the end I managed to get it working! For your reference, this is how I did it:

> SC01A:: Send {ASC 0252}   ; ü
>   +SC01A:: Send {ASC 0220}  ; Ü
>   SC00D:: Send {ASC 0223}   ; ß

The SC code at the beginning was needed to [identify the exact scancode](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic22881.html) of the keys that I wanted to manipulate. And only the ASC code in those brackets and the Send command brought up the right output that I wanted to have.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something even better than that. In [this site](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/) you will find a lot of examples of what can be done with Autohotkey . One of the example-programs is Accents v1.0. Just get the source code and change the accents to what ever you want.
You can always read the documentation. Autohotkey has a [nice enough one](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/).

*Edited after*:
To do what you requested in the comments:

```
a::
send {x}
return
+a::
send {X}
return
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link! I will for sure check out what I can find there. However, "Accents v1.0" does unfortunately not do the job for me. To explain better what I need, let's assume for a moment that I would (because of the language I write on the keyboard) never use the letter "a". Instead, I use a lot the letter "x" which (in this fictional example) does not exist on the keyboard. Thus, I want to exchange the "a" for "x" and "A" for "X". I know I can do it directly in the registry but I don't feel comfortable doing it there, especially as I know that it is somehow possible also with AHK...

Comment: So could anybody please help me to do it? As I am not a coder myself, it would take me years to learn the AHK documentation that user "Lombas" quoted above, as well... Or does somebody know maybe where to find a sample for the code that I need which I can then customize for myself? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: It's not that hard... you would learn ins a few days using the tutorials.. hehehe. Nevertheless, your code is above, in the edited answer.